# Androidplot ListView of XYPlot with only one XYPLOT centered horizontally

Tags: android, listview, graph, androidplot

I want to plot a single graph with the ListView of XYPlot. 
Why don't I used the XYPlot? 
This is because I have several graphs and I want to give the user the possibility to choose only one graph at a certain time. That is once the user choose an item, I draw the graph conrresponding to the chosen item. Moreover there is also the issue that scales are different for each item. That is if item1 scales for the Y-axis from 0 to 10, item2 might scale from -20 to 20. So drawing both on same graph with the scale will be a very bad user experience.

That is why I thought of the ListView of XYPlot.

But when I put one XYPlot, it becomes scrollable. I have tried used the wrap_content or match_parent on the layout_height of the xml code of the XYPlot but when I do so, the graph does appear.

This is the code of my ListView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The xml code of the XYPlot the I use to associate to the listView

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
        android:id="@+id/xyplot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="450dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above code works but that render the graph scrollable. Changes the code of the XYPlot to

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
        android:id="@+id/xyplot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

or even using **match_parent** as the **layout_height**, makes the XYPlot to disappear from the listView.

I was wondering how I can make the XYPlot graph centered horizontally (I want to avoid the user the pain of scrolling down before seeing the entire graph)

Any clues please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be not to use a `ListView`.  I'm not positive I fully understand your use case but it doesn't really sound like you need the `ListView`.

Having said that, if you do want to keep using `ListView`, a couple things to keep in mind when using `XYPlot` (or any other `Plot` type) in a scrollable view like `ListView`:

`XYPlot` has no implicit size so you can't use a `layout_width` or `layout_height` value of `wrap_content`.

Furthermore, `layout_height` should be specified dp as `match_parent` will generally result in a chicken and egg type scenario that typically manifests its self as an invisible plot as you observed. You can still safely use `match_parent` as your plot's `layout_width`.